# SLD style not imported in geoserver while publishing it through REST API

Tags: geoserver, sld, geoserver-rest-api

> I am using REST APIs to publish and change the default style of layers
> published in GeoServer. When I copy the SLD and paste it directly in
> the GeoServer styles it works fine. but while using REST API it omits
> the complete symbology and no style is assigned. imported symbology is
> as follows

```
<sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill/>
            <sld:Stroke/>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
```

> following script loads sld from local file and publishes it using REST API:

```
async function loadSld(urls) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(urls);
    sld = await response.text();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err, 'error loading sld');
  }

  const url = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles";
    await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS",
        Authorization: "Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy",
      },
      body: sld,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        res = response;
        console.log(res, 'response after sld');
        console.log(sld, 'sld');
        if (res.statusText !== "Created") {
         console.log(res, 'response');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
}
```

the sld is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1.0" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>Pakistan_with_Kashmir</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>Pakistan_with_Kashmir</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>0 - 1.6</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>0 - 1.6</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>PROVINCE_C</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>PROVINCE_C</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1.60000000000000009</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>1.6 - 3.2</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>1.6 - 3.2</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>PROVINCE_C</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1.60000000000000009</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>PROVINCE_C</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>3.20000000000000018</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ffbfbf</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>3.2 - 4.8</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>3.2 - 4.8</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>PROVINCE_C</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>3.20000000000000018</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>PROVINCE_C</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>4.79999999999999982</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff8080</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>4.8 - 6.4</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>4.8 - 6.4</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>PROVINCE_C</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>4.79999999999999982</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>PROVINCE_C</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>6.40000000000000036</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff4040</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>6.4 - 8</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>6.4 - 8</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>PROVINCE_C</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>6.40000000000000036</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>PROVINCE_C</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are posting a SLD 1.1 to GeoServer, but telling it, via the mime type, it's a SLD 1.0 instead.

Try using the SLD 1.1 mime type instead: `application/vnd.ogc.se+xml`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SLD 1.0, you can try this:

### Create style name

```sh
curl -u admin:pass -X POST 'https://site.com/geoserver/rest/styles' \
    --header 'Content-type: text/xml' \
    --data-raw "<style><name>style_name</name><filename>sld_name.sld</filename></style>"
```

### Upload style code in new style

```sh
curl -u admin:pass -X PUT "https://site.com/geoserver/rest/styles/style_name" \
    --header 'Content-type: application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml' \
    --data-binary "@local/path/to/sld_name.sld"
```

### You can use "Authorization Basic" instead of admin:pass

```sh
curl -X PUT "https://site.com/geoserver/rest/styles/style_name" \
    --header 'Content-type: application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml' \
    --header 'Authorization: Basic Y***************='
    --data-binary "@local/path/to/sld_name.sld"
```

### If use self-signed certificate for https, use -k option

```sh
curl -k -X PUT ****
```